# IdentityUser or own model

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, model, asp.net-identity

I was wondering if in case I have a project (ASP.NET MVC Core with EF Core) in which I create, edit and read models of the type `Person` , and I subsequently integrate ASP.NET Identity, if I should move all the properties of the `Person` model to the model `ApplicationUser : IdentityUser`

```
class Person {
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public List<Hobby> Hobbies { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to understand which properties I should move to ApplicationUser and which not.

Comment: It depends. Are your identity models in the same context as your table models? If so, and you need the  properties, add them.

Comment: so i should not have a Person model or i should have both matching?

Comment: How are we supposed to know? We know nothing about your project and the existing code base. Though: a `Person` sounds like a hugely more general concept than a `User`...

Comment: It depends on how your dbcontext is set up. You're not showing a whole lot so I'm speculating that Person and ApplicationUser are in separate contexts and that Person somewhat extends ApplicationUser. I would put the ApplicationUser  Guid in the Person table and use the Person table for all of the properties that aren't required for Identity.

Comment: My model contains only Age, Gender and Hobbies. Now my question is : I have to incorporate these properties in the Applicaton user Model or have a separated table called Person?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general question, how to design the db model is depends on how you will use this person model.

For example:

If this person is not this application user and no need login in for your application, it just need to show some person property like age, name as a table and query something. There is no need to add these property to the identity user.

You could just add a new dbset inside the dbcontext to let the ef core generate a new table named persons.

If this person's property is the application user properties and you want the application user contains these properties, I suggest you could modify the application user model class to work as a custom application user and use it laterly.

Details about how to create the custom user by modifying the model class, I suggest you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0#customize-the-model).

Comment: As far as I understood, Application user class model should have properties related to login so only email, password, verifiedEmail and name. Properties like age, gender and more info should be in another table(Person table). Am I wrong? Clearly if i do not have the need to have asp.net identity i only use the Person model.

Comment: As I said the applcation user class is used for login, if you no need login for your application, there is no need to use it.

Comment: I'am talking about the case that my application needs login...

Comment: I mean the what's the relationship between the person model and the application user model?